# Actionscript 3 filter items out of combobox

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox, mxml

So I have a combobox that should work as follows:

1. Click dropdown
2. Choose an item
3. item is moved into another list
4. Item can no longer be found in first combobox dropdown

So I created a combobox like:

```
    <s:ComboBox
            id="cbox"
            labelFunction="labels"
            dataProvider="{objects}"
            change="addFilter()"
            restrict="a-zA-Z0-9\-,_"
            width="100%"
            maxChars="32"
            prompt="add filter"
    />
```

My issue stems from calling `objects.refresh()`, as it fails in the `list.as` file (AS library) at the line `dataGroup.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, updateCompleteListenerA);`, where the `dataGroup` is null.

My filter function on the `objects` `ArrayCollection` is something like:

```
private function filterEcus(item:Object):Boolean {
     for each (var i:Object in secondList) {
        if (i.property == item.property) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //should not reach this
    return true;
}
```

I call the refresh at the end of the change handler.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler solution for your problem. I just tested it.
First you need to declare your comboboxes:

```
<s:ComboBox id="primaryCombobox" change="updateList(event)">
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:Object label="One"/>
        <fx:Object label="Two"/>
        <fx:Object label="Three"/>
        <fx:Object label="Four"/>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:ComboBox>

<s:ComboBox id="secondaryCombobox">
    <s:ArrayList>
        <!-- You need to declare an empty data provider. -->
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:ComboBox>
```

Then you use this function on the change handler:

```
private function updateList(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
{
    secondaryCombobox.dataProvider.addItem(primaryCombobox.selectedItem);
    primaryCombobox.dataProvider.removeItemAt(primaryCombobox.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, removing an item does not update the combobox, so I have to call `.refresh()`, which subsequently fails.

Comment: Try to not use a DataProvider with DataBinding. That's how it worked for me. You can later mimick data binding in the change event handler. myCombobox.dataProvider = someArrayList;

Comment: Interesting, I would really like an answer as to why my filter on the data is causing an issue. I removed binding but still fails on refresh.

Comment: With my code you don't really need to call refresh() since all the changes are applied instantly. Just try to copy and paste the example in a blank project to see the interaction.

Comment: Right, but my issue stems from changes not being applied, having to call refresh, then it failing. I attempted your solution in my project and it does not work as expected.